# Password format not liked by installer

Tags: windows, vmware, sql-server

I'm installing Chargeback and I get to the database-related information page (step 5 on page 17 of the users guide).

Using a Windows account (it is an administrator of the server and I am logged on as that user)
Username: DOMAIN\ServiceVMware-CB
Password: #$%UuuU2u (this isn't the password but it does start with #$% and is the same length and case)

I click the Test Connected and it returns back OK.

I click Next and then I am given a warning telling me that the account does not have the right permissions. Check that it has log on as a service etc etc etc.

I quit the installer.
I change the password in the domain to Uuuuuu3
I reboot the server
I restart the server
The installer has no problems with the newer password.

I'm not fussed either way, I'm just trying to save someone else the pain and perhaps the allowed password format could be added to the documentation.

BTW I am using Server 2008 SP2 x64 with SQL Express 2005 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the password in quotation marks - so it would read `"#$%UuuU2u"`.

If this does not work, it is a weakness of the software and you are out of luck.

I personally had something similar recently, I had a character in a password that the installer simply wrote into a script. It did not work as it was a special character but putting the whole lot in quotation marks did the job.